# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d \theta}{1+2p\cos \theta+p^2}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Evaluate $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d \theta}{1+2p\cos \theta+p^2}$$ where $0<|p|<1$

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d \theta}{1+2p\cos \theta+p^2}=\frac{1}{i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{d z}{z(1+pz+\frac{p}{z}+p^2)}=\frac{1}{i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{d z}{z+pz^2+p+zp^2}=\\ =\frac{1}{i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{d z}{pz^2+(p^2+1)z+p}$$

$pz^2+(p^2+1)z+p=0$ Then $z_1=0,z_2=-p$

$Res(f,0)=lim_{z\to 0}\frac{z}{z(z+p)}=\frac{1}{p}$

$Res(f,-p)=lim_{z\to -p}\frac{(z+p)}{z(z+p)}=-\frac{1}{p}$

So it is $\frac{1}{i}2\pi i (\frac{1}{p}-\frac{1}{p})=0$

But the answer is $\frac{2\pi }{1-p^2}$

Where did it went wrong?

Comment: More accurately: your denominator does not have a root at 0.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using the residue theorem, calculate $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{1-2a\cos{\theta}+a^2}d\theta$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2838452/using-the-residue-theorem-calculate-int-02-pi-frac11-2a-cos-thetaa)

Answer (score 4):

Your integrand has poles at $-p$ and $-1/p$. The point $0$ is not a pole, so there is no need to incorporate the residue there. Your calculation should be as follows:

We first note that when $0 < |p| <1$ then the pole at $-1/p$ lies outside the unit circle, so it will not affect the integral.

The residue at $-p$ is $$\lim_{z \to -p}\frac{(z+p)}{p(z+p)(z+1/p)}= \frac{1}{1-p^2}$$

Thus the desired integral is $2\pi i\cdot\frac{1}{i}\frac{1}{1-p^2} = \frac{2\pi}{1-p^2}$ by residue theorem